# Using argv[] in CC compiler for c++

Tags: c++, cc

In g++ compiler, my program works perfectly, however, in CC compiler, I get an error.

The following line: `Shape s[atoi(argv[1])];` gives the error:
error: An integer constant expression is required within the array subscript operator.

Then, I tried changing it to: `int i = atoi(argv[1]);` followed by `Shape s[i];`, but I still get the same error.

I need argv[1] because it gets from the command line how many shapes to make.
e.g. ./program 10
It should make `Team s[10];`

How do I get argv[] to work with CC compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrays, the size specified must be a constant. So while you can do this:

```
Team s[10];
```

You cannot do this:

```
int size = 10;
Team s[size];
```

Instead, you have to do this:

```
int size = 10;
Team* s = new Team[size];
// do stuff
delete[] s;
```

Comment: Which is a horrible solution.  The only valid solution would be `std::vector<Team> s(size)`.

Comment: Not everyone wants to use vectors. He asked a question and the correct answer is not to give then an alternative (no matter now much better you consider it to be), but to answer what was asked.

Comment: It's not a question of whether you want to or not: `std::vector` is the only correct solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Team s[10];

would create array on stack, but this is possible only if size is constant expression. If you want dynamic array then you have to create array dynamically with a call to `new[]`

```
int size = atoi( argv[1]);
Team* s = new Team[ size];
```

Prefer `std::vector<Team> tv(size);` that will ease the memory management (and after all, sooner or later, you will have to learn STL library, start today).

Comment: Then fix the memory leak (preferably by using `std::vector`, rather than more error-prone pointer juggling).

Comment: Also, VLAs in C++ are a conforming extension in g++, which explains why it worked there.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not sure what you mean by "conforming extension".  The C++ standard requires a diagnostic.  (Of course, without the proper options, g++ isn't any more a C++ compiler than any of the others.  Try using `-std=c++11`, for starters.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: As it does not change the meaning of any valid code, and with the proper options will cause a warning, it's a conforming extension. Though yes, conforming is superfluous there, and going for pure C++ (and letting the compiler enforce that standard) is probably better.

Comment: @Deduplicator The standard requires a diagnostic when you compile the code.  If the compiler doesn't generate one, then it's not conforming.  (But as I said, most compilers are _not_ conforming without special options.  G++ is conforming if you use the correct options.)

Answer (score 1):

In standard C++, the size of an array must be a compile-time constant. GCC allows variable-length arrays as a non-standard extension; other compilers don't.

To do this portably, you'll need dynamically allocated array:

```
#include <memory>

std::vector<Shape> s(atoi(argv[1]));
```

Comment: When is an extension a standard extension? Who all must have implemented it?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I don't know what do you mean; extensions aren't standard. Are you just objecting to my use of a redundant word for emphasis?